# Given x, y are real number that are not equal to 1. Find all x, y that satisfy:

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

Given x, y are real numbers that are not equal to 1. Find all x, y that satisfy:

$x^8+y^7=x(1+y^7)$
and
$y^8+x^7=y(1+x^7)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of the two polynomials $f=x^8+y^7-x(1+y^7)$ and $g=y^8+x^7-y(1+x^7)$ is given by a polynomial in $x$, which has four real roots, namely $x=0,1,-1$ and $x=0.502017055178$, which is the real root of
$$
x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x - 1=0.
$$
The roots are the common solutions for $f=g=0$.

Hence the real solutions are
$$
(x,y)=(0,0), (1,1), (-1,-1)
$$
and
$$
(x,y)=(0.502017055178, 1), (1,0.502017055178).
$$

Comment: I wonder how you can convert the two polynomials into $x(x^{49}-x^{48}-x^7+1)$
I'm still a secondary student so can you explain it more clearly please?

Comment: @Alvm. $(x-1) x (x+1) \left(x^2-x+1\right) \left(x^2+x+1\right)
   \left(x^{43}-x^{42}+x^{37}-x^{36}+x^{31}-x^{30}+x^{25}-x^{24}+x
   ^{19}-x^{18}+x^{13}-x^{12}+x^7-x^6-1\right)$

Comment: FWIW I suspect that by eliminating $x, y = 1$, that gets rid of the solution $x = 1, y ^8 + 1 = 2y$, and the ones we're left with must satisfy $ x = y $ which you've found the values of.

Comment: @CalvinLin I am sorry, but I had a typo in the second equation, where I confused $x^7$ with $y^7$. Now it seems to be OK, but we still have two special real solutions, which are not integral.

Comment: Thanks for checking! $(y^8 + 1 - 2y ) / (y-1)$ is the degree 7 polynomial that you found, so my above suspicion could be on the right track.